# jsf noSelectionLabel ln selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf

How to provide an noSelectionLabel in selectOneMenu with converter?

Using noSelectionLabel in selectItem throus a NullPointerException in converter class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check in converter if the incoming value is null and if so, then return immediately.

```
if (value == null) {
    return null;
}

// ...
return convertedValue;
```

Comment: itemLabel is passed as value in converter so value is not null, the condition fails

Comment: Wait, there's actually no `noSelectionLabel` attribute in standard JSF `<f:selectItems>` tag. Are you using Seam `<s:selectItems>`? As to the problem, what exactly is `null` in the converter? You should after all just do a simple nullcheck on it to bypass the access to the `null` reference.

Comment: Sorry, typo error this is my code <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" escape="true" noSelectionOption="true"/>

Comment: Well, the answer still stands. Just add a simple nullcheck to the converter.